# what is the point of calling selectAll when there are no existing nodes yet on D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

when i do this :

```
var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
    .data(links)
    .enter().append('path')
        .attr('class', 'link')
        .attr('d', diagonal)
```

There is no node with the `.link` class. So selectAll returns en empty selection. But i've found that, when you call this for the first time, you can `selectAll('whaterverYouWant')`

That is because D3 doesn't matter about what you select, as you provide the tag name and the classes later `.append('path')`, `.attr(class ...)`.

And, if you want to select elements that already exist, i read in the doc that `.enter` returns a placeholder selection. But if it returns a selection of placeholders (anonymous tags with .link class ?), there is no point to append a path to a path.

When i call .append, it does what i want, i.e. append a path to svg. But i don't understand the logic behind that. (I'm glad it works though, because d3 is powerful)

So, ok i selectAll('anything') and append what i want, regardless of what i selected. But if i try this:

```
d3.select('#savestring-debug')
    .selectAll('div')
    .data(debugobjs)
    .enter().append('span')
    .attr('style', function(d) { return 'background:#'+d.color })
    .text(function(d) { return d.aff });
```

This would create placeholders for divs, but i append spans. Actually spans are created but i'm still looking for my divs ;)

So, what is the principle behind selectAll >> data >> enter >> append ?

thanks

Comment: There is plenty of material that explains this on the D3 website, in particular [this](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) and [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principle behind selectAll > data > enter > append is explained pretty well by 
Mike Bostock here: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/ where he explains the concept of the data-join. I can't speak with any authority on the right way to use selectAll, but the way I use it is to select all of the elements I am going to be modifying-appending-removing within the part of the SVG that I need to modify.

So if I'm working with "rects" in a certain area, I'll do something like this:

```
var svg = d3.select('#graphID')
     .append("svg")
     .attr("width", 300)
     .attr("height", 500);

var graphGroup = self.svg.append("g");

//...Inside a render function

//just want all the "rect" elements in graphGroup
var rects = graphGroup.selectAll("rect")
                      .data(dataset);

//depending on dataset new rects will need to be appendend
rects.enter()
     .append("rect")
     .attr("x", 0)
     .attr("y", 0)
     .attr("width", 0)
     .attr("height", 0)

//all rects are transitioned to new co-ordinates
rects.transition().duration(500)
                  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                           return xScale(i); 
                   })
                  .attr("y", function(d) {
                           return h - yScale(d);
                   })
                  .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
                  .attr("height", function(d){
                       return yScale(d);
                   })

//rects that have no data associated with them are removed
rects.exit()
     .transition()
     .duration(500)
     .attr("x", -xScale.rangeBand())
     .remove();
```

With the idea that I could have other rects in the SVG that do not belong to graphGroup. I  just selectAll the rects in a certain area and work on them when needed.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't understand in your example whiy you still need to selectAll('rect') in order to append new rects on the SVG. You could basically append them to the svg.var and then selectAll your rects to move them. So i will read the link you pointed, all of this will hopefully be clear then.

Comment: Yeah it's weird if you think about it, but try to think about reusable code patterns. The same code above will draw the graph the first time and any time I need to update the graph. The first time the graph is drawn there are no "rect" so selectAll("rect") returns an empty selection. Then I do data(dataset), enter() and append("rect"). Finally the "rect" are added to the DOM. The selectAll becomes super useful if I need to update the graph, I can find all the "rect" that exist in the DOM and update/remove them.

Comment: yeah the tutorials are worth reading, they should be linked on the top page of the site

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question and a slightly odd property of D3. If you look carefully how anything is done in D3 you'll notice that everything is added by appending to what is previously created. So the logic behind having the svg.selectAll('whatever class of stuff you're going to add') is that you are kinda making a placeholder for where whatever you are about append to go. It's like the svg is a wall and you're hanging hooks on the upper ridge for you to THEN hang your paintings from. If you don't have the selectAll, I just tried this, you will still append whatever you were gonna make to the page, but it won't be appended to the svg.

The data-->enter-->append is basically saying for each element in the larger data file that you are passing into the data function, make a new element, and append this element to my selection with such and such properties (set when you use the .attr).